# webpack-hot-middleware webpack express typescript

Tags: node.js, express

I'm trying to set up webpack-hot-middleware on my node api 
but when I made a change on welcome.controller.ts, the console shows the build process but I can't see the changes, what I'm missing?, I'm using typescript and webpack, here is my setup:

Webpack.config.js

```
var fs = require('fs');
var webpack = require('webpack');
var path = require("path");
var nodeModules = {};
fs.readdirSync('node_modules')
.filter(function (x) {
    return ['.bin'].indexOf(x) === -1;
})
.forEach(function (mod) {
    nodeModules[mod] = 'commonjs ' + mod;
});

module.exports = {
entry: [
    'webpack-hot-middleware/client?
path=http://localhost:3000/__webpack_hmr&reload=true',
    './src/server'
],
output: {
    path:  __dirname + '/dist',
    filename: 'server.js',
    publicPath: '/'
},
devServer: {
    contentBase: './src'
  },
node: {
    __dirname: false,
    __filename: false
},
resolve: {
    // Add '.ts' and '.tsx' as a resolvable extension.
    extensions: ['.webpack.js', '.web.js', '.ts', '.tsx', '.js'],
},
devtool: '#source-map',

plugins: [
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new webpack.NoEmitOnErrorsPlugin()
],
module: {
    loaders: [
        // All files with a '.ts' or '.tsx'
        // extension will be handled by 'ts-loader'
        {
            test: /\.tsx?$/,
            loader: 'ts-loader',
        },
    ],
},
target: 'node',
externals: nodeModules
};
```

server.ts

```
import * as express from 'express';
import * as webpack from 'webpack';
import * as webpackDevMiddleware from  'webpack-dev-middleware';
import * as webpackHotMiddleware from 'webpack-hot-middleware';
import * as dotenv from 'dotenv';
import * as bodyParser from 'body-parser';
import * as config from '../webpack.config';
import * as welcomeController from './controllers/welcome.controller';
import * as path from 'path'
dotenv.config();

const compiler = webpack(config);
const app = express();


app.use(webpackDevMiddleware(compiler, {
  publicPath: config.output.path,
  stats: {colors: true},
  noInfo: true
}));

app.use(webpackHotMiddleware(compiler,  {
  log: console.log, path: '/__webpack_hmr', heartbeat: 10 * 1000
}));


app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use('/', express.static(path.join(__dirname, "/dist")));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.get('/', welcomeController.index);

app.listen(app.get('port'), () => {
  console.log(('App is running at http://localhost:%d in %s mode'),
    app.get('port'), app.get('env'));
  console.log('Press CTRL-C to stop\n');
});

if (module.hot) {
  module.hot.accept('./server', () => {
   console.log('si')
  });
}

module.exports = app;
```

welcome.controller.ts

```
import { Request, Response } from 'express';
let pkg = require(__dirname + '/../../package.json');

export let index = (req: Request, res: Response) => {
  res.json({
    message: 'Welcome to API sekeleton.',
    version: pkg.version,
  });
}
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "projectq",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "webpack --config webpack.config.js",
    "start": "npm run build && node ./dist/server.js"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "dotenv": "^5.0.0",
    "express": "^4.16.2",
    "ts-loader": "^3.5.0",
    "typescript": "^2.7.1",
    "typings": "^2.1.1",
    "webpack": "^3.11.0",
    "webpack-dev-middleware": "^2.0.5",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.11.1",
    "webpack-hot-middleware": "^2.21.0"
  }
}
```